# Switch-User is not functional on lightdm

Tags: debian, users, lightdm

On lightdm pressing the Switch User button does nothing.
`dm-tool switch-to-greeter` switches to the greeter, but does not seem to lock my current account.
Is there any way to fix this, or even to debug this?

In `/var/syslog` I seem to get this error: `(gnome-shell:1303): mutter-WARNING **: STACK_OP_RAISE_ABOVE: window 0x6701a00016 not in stack` which seems related.

I am running debian jessie.